# Build Failure: Failed to re-package resources - Unity Game Engine

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, plugins

When I try to generate Android build, I was getting following error in Unity console:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   /Users/siddharthtrivedi/Company/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "/Users/siddharthtrivedi/Company/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.stansassets.androidnative:com.google.firebase.unity:com.android.vending.billing:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.stansassets.social:com.stansassets.androidnative:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base.license:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.android.gms.tasks.license:com.google.firebase.measurement:com.google.firebase.measurement_impl:com.google.firebase.measurement.impl.license:com.google.firebase.measurement.license:com.google.firebase.unity.app:com.google.firebase.firebase_common:com.google.firebase.firebase.common.license:com.google.firebase.firebase_core:com.google.firebase.iid:com.google.firebase.firebase.iid.license:com.google.firebase.messaging:com.google.firebase.firebase.messaging.license:com.google.firebase.unity.messaging:com.unity.purchasing:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/AN_Res/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/Firebase/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GoogleAIDL/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GooglePlay/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/an_social/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/androidnative/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/cardview-v7-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.cardview-v7-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.customtabs-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-ui-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-utils-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-fragment-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-v4-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.firebase.firebase-common-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-11.8.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/common/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/customtabs-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-compat-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-ui-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-utils-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-fragment-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-media-compat-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4-25.3.1/res" -S "/Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-vector-drawable-25.3.1/res"
>
> stderr[
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material for
>   configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:scrollIndicators from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:26:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for
>   configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:45:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:36:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material for
>   configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration
>   v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:24:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout for
>   configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:59:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout for configuration
>   v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml:
>   note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml:47:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml:23:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from 
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/abc_select_dialog_material for configuration
>   v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment for
>   configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:47:
>   note: removing attribute
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from
>   
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:
>   note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource
>   sportsbetkingz.com:layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment
>   for configuration v17.
>   /Volumes/Work/Company/Unity/Projects/DA_Android/SportsBetKingz2017/Temp/StagingArea/a

Upto now I have integrated Mobile Social, Facebook, UniPaste, UnityIAP plugin. After all these integration Android build exported properly but lastly I have integrated FirebaseMessaging plugin then after above kind of error started and I can't able to export build.

Already I have solved so many errors during build export but above error is not properly descriptive so I can't able to understand the exact meaning. So please someone provide me some guidance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set "Build System" to "Gradle" in Build Settings window.

Comment: Thanks for this reply - But after changing build system to gradle - I am getting this kind of error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G88ZtRTaxNx28i4N-prWSRHmivmJZEVe

Comment: update android sdk to api 26, 
resolve android dependecies(force resolve), 
try to build with gradle build system

Comment: Sorry after installing API 26 with Android Studio, I started getting this error so at present I can't able to test this thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708186/setup-android-studio-sdk-with-unity

Comment: Still I am getting same error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dEXv2ofUWAzP7_MI8GiuhGWOBsnF9maQ

Comment: Seems you don't have label `android:name` inside your manifest. You should have smth like this -
`android:name="App Name" android:label="@string/app_name"`
Provide the full build log and manifest for detailed information. To get build log information run in terminal
`open ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your project with a later version of Unity. I received the same issue with Unity 5 but it worked when I attempted to export it with Unity 2017 (lowest).