# Setup Android Studio SDK with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, path, sdk

I have recently downloaded Android Studio with its SDK and set custom path for SDK download and its get completed. 
My Android Studio correctly detected downloaded SDK and setup running fine with this.

But when I try to set path in Unity its not able to set, again and again same location related popup get opened.
Please see below image file:

[image]

Why path not get set that I don't know!! Upto now I used Android SDK with Eclipse so all things work good with me. But after upgrading to Android Studio I can't able to SDK path.

Please give me some help so I can able to export Android build.
Same problem running with Windows platform too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have Android SDK Tools in your folder.

Download [Android SDK Tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip) and insert it in your sdk folder.

Comment: yes this worked - thanks :)
basically if we download SDK through Android Studio then why I was getting this kind of problem? Also from where I can download tools folder for Windows and Mac systems?

Comment: Actually you can to download sdk tools via SDK Manager in Android Studio.
BUT the worked tools version for unity is 25.5.2. The latest version (26.1.1) doesn't work properly in unity, so you haven't to update to it. So you should download this version manually via google repo. Windows version is [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip)

Comment: Where can I found list of Google Repository? I try to cut down your link but list not found. I am asking this for future purpose.

Comment: **[There](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools)** is the latest version only. **[There](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-tools.html)** is all others versions. Version up to 25.2.5 inclusive works in unity properly.
**[Windows version is here again](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip)**